# How can I address the error I'm being shown when attempting to create a card using the Stripe API?

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for my app.  I am using the code shown below.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Token::create(array(
  "card" => array(

    "number" => "4242424242424242",
    "exp_month" => 1,
    "exp_year" => 2017,
    "cvc" => "314"
  )
));
```

but the following error is showing on my page:

> You must verify a phone number on your Stripe account before you can send raw credit card numbers to the Stripe API. You can avoid this requirement by using Stripe.js the Stripe mobile bindings, or Stripe Checkout. For more information.

Comment: You should follow this [Quickstart guide](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart). That's what is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that card numbers are going through your server. Unless
>   your organization is [PCI certified](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) and allowed to directly
>   manipulate card numbers, you should not do this and instead should
>   create the tokens in your client-side code, using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or
>   [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) (or one of our [mobile SDKs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile) if your client-side code
>   is actually a native mobile app)
>
> If your company is **PCI certified** then you'll need to activate your
>   account and provide a phone number as the error message says.

Answer taken from [botbot.me](https://botbot.me/freenode/stripe/2017-10-17/?msg=25824969&page=5)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I verified my Stripe phone number, and it worked fine